# Group a set of array files into ONE large array in R

Tags: arrays, r, multidimensional-array

I would like to merge a set of 100 independent array files, *dim= ({x=684,y=483,t=3} (t=time))*, into one large array with *dim=(x=684,y=483,t=3,runs=100)*.

I have ran a serious of (100) simulation in a loop form. 
To distinguish each simulation I did:

```
run.number<-as.integer(runif(1)*10^5) # sets a random number with a small likelihood of repeating itself within the 100 runs
hP=paste0(run.number,".P_dynamics",”.RData”)# file name
save(historyP,file=hP) # save array with name = “hP”
```

example of a saved files: **5468.P_dynamics.RData** and **61952.P_dynamics.RData***

problem:
I have 100 independent  array files like above, and I would like to group them into one array, as:

```
dynamics<-array(NA,c(x=684,y=483,t=3,runs=100))
```

How can I do this?  Taking into account that the generated number “run.number” is a large random number. Additionally, the order of runs is very important. Hence older file has to come before the newer array.

Comment: historyP is the original array
the saved file name is: ("a random number"+".P_dynamics"+”.RData”)

Comment: when I load the data, the file name is "Pdynamics.RData"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`abind::abind()` combines multi-dimensional arrays, it is easy. The difficult point is preparation of arguments of `abind()`.

(1) move all `xxx.RData` into a folder.
(2) get the filenames, change it into old-new order, and get the object names of array.

```
library(dplyr); library(abind)

fl <- list.files("FolderName", full = T)
fl <- fl[order(file.info(fl)$ctime)]
array_names <- sapply(fl, load) %>% as.vector()
```

- When all `array` has a **unique** name;

(3) load all xxx.RData, make the list of arrays by `lapply()`, and combine it using `abind::abind(list, rev.along = 0)`

```
for(i in fl) load(i)
ar <- lapply(array_names, function(x) eval(parse(text = x))) %>% 
  abind(rev.along = 0)
```

- When `array`s have a common name (i.e., `length(unique(array_names))` is `1`);

(3) separately `attach()` and put into `list()`

```
uni_n <- unique(array_names)
array_list <- list()

for(i in 1:length(fl)) {
  attach(fl[i])
  array_list[[i]] <- eval(parse(text = uni_n))
  detach()
}

ar <- abind(array_list, rev.along = 0)
```

Comment: many thanks
It works perfectly

I have also managed to developed a similar way, which works as well

but many thanks

Answer (score 1):

1) create a list with all "R.data" files
they come ordered, so that is not a problem

```
res=list.files('.')
indexP=grep(pattern="P_dynamics.RData",res) #location of P dynamics files
resP=res[indexP] #P dynamics files list
```

2) construction P dynamics global array

```
load(paste0(resP[1]))
Pdynamics=historyP 
for (i in resP[-1])
{
  load(i)  
  Pdynamics=abind(Pdynamics,historyP,along=4)
}
```